# Decrement date by 1 day

Tags: jmeter

Parameter "date" holds the value of one of the date captured from response data. Now, we have to pass the value of past date.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `${__timeShift(dd/MM/yyyy,${date},-P1D,,)} `

Comment: You probably have different format /space or special character in variable

Comment: You can't use it inside JSR223 script

Comment: ok. what would be the other option?

Answer (score 1):

Use [__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function

```
 ${__timeShift(dd/MM/yyyy,05/01/2019,-P1D,,)}
```

> Examples:
>
> ```
> ${__timeShift(dd/MM/yyyy,21/01/2018,P2D,,)}
> ```
>
> returns 23/01/2018